# Tempo entre duas datas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como faço para saber a quantidade de tempo em dias, horas e meses entre duas datas usando Python? Por exemplo saber quantos dias, meses e anos há entre 22/11/213 e 25/03/2014.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está a solução, não completa porque necessita validações, deixarei para você.

```
from datetime import *

data1 = input("Digite a primeira data em formato dd/mm/aaaa: ")
data2 = input("Digite a segunda data em formato dd/mm/aaaa: ") #Aqui você pode validar as entradas, irei deixar pra você

data1 = datetime.strptime(data1, "%d/%m/%Y").date() #Converte input em data no formato "aaaa-mm-dd", o parâmetro "%d/%m/%Y" retorna erro caso o usuário digite fora desse formato, mas não o transforma.
data2 = datetime.strptime(data2, "%d/%m/%Y").date()
data1 = data1.toordinal() #Convertendo em dias
data2 = data2.toordinal() #Convertendo em dias
dias = data1 - data2 #Diferenca em dias
anos, dias = dias // 365, dias % 365
meses, dias = dias // 30, dias % 30
print(dias," ",meses," ",anos)
```